# Suppose $P, N$ are sub-modules of a module $M$. Then there exist natural isomorphisms..

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Suppose $P, N$ are sub-modules of a module $M$. Then there exist natural isomorphisms $$(1) \ \ \frac{P+N}{P} \approx \frac{N}{N \cap P}  \ \  \text{ and } \ (2)\ \  \frac{P+N}{N} \approx \frac{P}{N \cap P}.$$

First we define a map $g : P+N \to \frac{N}{N \cap P}$ as $g(x+y) = y + (N \cap P)$ for all $x \in P$ and $y \in N$. One can easily check that $g$ is well-defined, surjective and a homomorphism.

Also I have found that $\ker(g) =  \frac{N}{N \cap P}$.

Then I am trying to apply the epimorphism theorem...

But I cannot conclude from here......Help Needed!

Thanks..

Comment: $\mathrm{Ker}(g)$ doesn't look right -- it should consist of elements of $P+N$, but $\frac{N}{N\cap P}$ is not a subset of $P+N$.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in another direction:

$$f:N\rightarrow (P+N)/P,n\mapsto n+P$$

Check this is a well-defined module homomorphism. Check this is a surjection. Check the kernel is $N\cap P$. Then apply your epimorphism theorem (I think you are referring to the first isomorphism theorem. The result you are trying to prove is also called the second isomorphism theorem.)